# About invalid agrument Foreach

Tags: php

h3llo all,

I have created this foreach to know how many box per sector are in database:

```
if (($date_start !='') AND ($date_end !='')) {
  foreach($qty_box_sector->query('
  SELECT *, COUNT(*)  
  FROM boxes
  LEFT JOIN sectors ON sector_id = box_sector_id
  LEFT JOIN users ON user_id = box_user_id
  WHERE box_user_id = '.$user_id.'
  AND box_create_date BETWEEN '.$date_start.' 00:00:00 AND '.$date_end.' 23:59:59
  GROUP BY box_sector_id') as $row) {
  ... echos here ...
}
```

All working good, but when I try to apply AND/BETWEEN condition like this:

```
AND box_create_date BETWEEN '.$date_Start.' 00:00:00 AND '.$date_end.' 23:59:59
```

I have this warning

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

Whats wrong? :-)

Comment: Look at the code coloring. You are missing a `'` before `as $row) {`

Comment: Sorry, mistake copy/past code, i already have     '     before as $row) {

Comment: So echo out the error code and show us that

Comment: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /return.php on line 185 (line 185 is GROUP BY ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead, the dates in your query have to be wrapped in quotes as well

```
if (($date_start !='') AND ($date_end !='')) {
  foreach($qty_box_sector->query(
  "SELECT *, COUNT(*)  
   FROM boxes
     LEFT JOIN sectors ON sector_id = box_sector_id
     LEFT JOIN users ON user_id = box_user_id
   WHERE box_user_id = '$user_id'
     AND box_create_date BETWEEN '$date_start 00:00:00' 
                             AND '$date_end 23:59:59' 
   GROUP BY box_sector_id") as $row) {
  ... echos here ...
}
```

Comment: :-) TKS for helps